# App crashing due to NSInvalidArgumentException from "push" segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Before this question gets down voted by users that think they know everything please read the entire question prior to saying this is a duplicate. *It is not*.

My application has a UITabBarController with a view that it itself **is** embedded in a UINavigationController. So as of right now the order of execution when the app runs is this:

`UITabBarController -> NavigationController -> HomeViewController`

Since I have a conditional on my `HomeViewController` to check if the user is already logged in, if not to:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
```

When the user is not logged in, the app crashes with the following:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'`

However, if I take my `SignUpViewController` and embed it in a `NavigationController` , this works perfectly fine, but I shouldn't have to do this since my `HomeViewController` is already embedded in a `NavigationController`

Any ideas why this could be happening?

**EDIT:**
The app now only runs smoothy if I have 2 `UINavigationControllers` doesn't make sense. Attached is my storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of your storyboard, please?

Comment: I'm guessing the orange VC is SignUpViewController, and this is the storyboard when you embed it in a UINavigationController? If so, please also add the storyboard which produces the crash.

Comment: Yes that is correct @GuillaumeAlgis

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the storyboard before fixing the error.